# Meaning of the expression "$\mu$ a.e."

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, notation

In the monotone convergence theorem:

Let $g_n\geq 0$ be a sequence of measurable functions, such that $g_n \uparrow g\;\; \mu \text{ a.e.},$ i.e. $g_n(\omega) \leq g_{n+1}(\omega)\;\; \mu \text{ a.e.},$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} g_n(\omega) = g(\omega)\;\; \mu \text{ a.e.},$ then $\int g_n d\mu \uparrow \int g d\mu.$

I wrote the theorem just for context. And I understand that "$\text{a.e.}$" is a way of excluding sets or subsets that are not measurable, and that the measure is $\mu.$

But I don't see the intent or meaning of the expression $$\mu\text{ a.e.}$$

Comment: "a.e." is a way of qualifying a statement by ignoring sets of measure zero, not a way of excluding subsets that are not measurable. (All of this with reference to whatever measure one has chosen, in this case, apparently $\mu$.)

Comment: @leslietownes Fine distinction, there! So the idea is that the sets are still "there" (not excluded) but they are ignored in whatever theorem is stated, because they have measure zero?

Comment: Yeah. My "ignoring" might have been a poorly chosen word but the informal spirit of a.e. statements is definitely along the lines of "We don't care if this condition fails a little bit, and certainly won't bother ourselves about identifying the exact set where it does fail, as long as we assume or can prove that it only fails on a set of measure zero."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means almost everywhere with respect to the measure $\mu$: for short, $\mu$-almost-everywhere. Id est, that the set of points where the condition fails is contained in a measurable set $S$ such that $\mu(S)=0$.

Comment: Mu defaults to Lebesgue, unless o.w. specified? Or is it lambda that usually implies Lebesgue?

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate Not necessarily: in point of fact I would contend that $\mu$ is more often used to indicate a generic measure ($\mu$ reads *m* in Greek) and that $\lambda$ is more common for the Lebesgue measure ($\lambda$ reads *l* in Greek).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics) This could help you for definition of a measure. Lebesgue measure is just one possible measure.

Comment: Agreeing with the above two comments. General treatments of integration (things like the monotone convergence theorem being a great example) generally do not specify or default to any particular measure, because doing so would lose a whole lot of generality without simplifying the proofs. Sometimes you will see theorems with hypotheses on the *properties* of a measure, and often these properties resemble or generalize those of Lebesgue measure

Comment: @Lizzi Understood - the follow-up question was simply whether the most usual Greek letter assignment for the Lebesgue was $\mu$ or $\lambda.$